# Python: instantiaing an object inside a method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have the following code:

```
class Fish():
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.color = color
        self.size = size

    def getInfo(self):
        return self.size, self.color


class Catch():

    def func1(self):
        catFish = Fish('blue', 'big')
        return catFish

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bob=Catch()
    bob.func1()
    catFish.getInfo()
```

When I try to do catFish.getInfo() I get the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test4.py", line 58, in <module>
    catFish.getInfo()
    NameError: name 'catFish' is not defined
```

I'm assuming this is because the local variable catFish gets dumped when the method, func1 ends. Is there a way to instantiate an object inside a method and be able to access that object after the method ends?

Comment: The code you actually posted will fail on `func1` not being defined - is that supposed to be `test` instead?  Assuming you do actually invoke `Catch.test()` at some point, assign its return value to a variable - that's what you can call `.getInfo()` on.

Comment: Whoops typo just fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm assuming this is because the local variable catFish gets dumped when the method, func1 ends.

Yep, your assumption is correct.

Or to be precise, the *name* `catFish` goes out of scope once the method ends. That means the underlying object can no longer be accessed by the name `catFish`, but the object is still sitting somewhere in memory. You can make it available to code outside the method by returning it and giving it another name.

In this code sample, you do return the object formerly known as `catFish` from the `func1()` method, but you don't give it a new name. To do so, you would just have to write

```
new_name = bob.func1()
```

Then you have access to the same object that was called `catFish` when it was in the method, now called `new_name`.

In general, you might want to read about [variable scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) to understand just where you can use any particular name to access an object, and when the name is no longer valid.

Comment: Very informative, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Variable catFish is out of scope meaning it is defined inside a method so any code outside that method cannot access it.

Comment: I realize this but surely there must be a way to simply instantiate an object inside a method and have be accessible outside of the method.